# how to use union in matlab to get the disjunction of closed intervals?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to use the union function in MATLAB to obtain the disjunction of two closed regions of the form `[a,b]` and `[c,d]`.

For e.g.

```
a=[1 3];
b=[3 6];
c=union(a,b)
```

I am getting the answer as `c = [1 3 6]`, whereas I want the answer to be only `[1 6]`.

Is there some trick I can play with the union function to achieve

As per the suggestion by @bernhard, I can use `setxor` to achieve this.

But supposing my matrix looks like

```
a[1 2: 3 5: 2 4}; 
b=[2 4]; 
c=setxor(a,b,'rows')
```

gives the output as `[1 2: 3 5]`.

But as before my answer should be of the form `[1 5]`. What do I need to do to get that?

Comment: Hello hektor, there are a number of problems here: 1) you explain what the expected result is, but not why that result is expected. Notice that Matlab has no representation of (real number) intervals. 2) It's ok to answer your own question, but as an answer, not within the question. 3) The code in your question is full of typos. I don't know what `a[1 2: 3 5: 2 4};` is supposed to mean and neither does Matlab. 4) You write that Bernard's answer is not what you are looking for – why do you accept it then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that what you are trying to achieve can be obtained by

```
setxor(a,b)
```

Comment: supposing my matrix looks like a[1 2: 3 5: 2 4}; b=[[2 4]; c=setxor(a,b,'rows') gives the output as [ 1 2: 3 5]. But as before my answer should be of the form [1 5]. What do i need to do to get that?

Comment: Based on what should your answer be `[1 5]`? You only have two-column vectors in the sets you're checking. `[1 5]` is not even in either of you sets, so getting it as a result would be weird.